# Java and Pubsubhubbub

Tags: java, push, google-code, websub

I just wanted to try out the java client for pubsubhubbub from google code (https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub-java/downloads/list). So I downloaded the code, signed up at SuperFeedr and tried to connect to their hub. In fact I modified the test class the is provided with the subscriber client.

```
sb.subscribe("http://superfeedr.com/hubbub",
                "https://some.blog", hostname, null, null);
```

hostname is the name of the server I created by using the class *Web* . Server is reachable from the web.

But I all get is this exception in the *GetThread* class:
org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException: Authentication challenge is empty

Does anybody have a hint?

Cheers,

Andi

PS: Up to now it's quite tedious to get PuSH working, e.g. at SuperFeedr they tell you what to do (http://superfeedr.com/documentation#pubsubhubbub_implementation) but not how? I tried to implement what's necessary for push my self (HttpClient, PostMethod with parameters,etc.) but nothing works....

Comment: This may be a bug in the java implementation. Have you tried another hub? Or even another, non-java, implementation?

Comment: Maybe posting to the Superfeed group could help?

Comment: I'll try that. But anyway, isn't there anybody using PuSH successfully who can provide a working example? Though it's hyped quite a lot during this year, you can hardly find good tutorials...

Comment: Still nobody who uses pubsubhubbub with java? Cannot believe that this is so hyped and you cannot find any working example...